# Crystal Reports 8.5 Formula Definition Location?

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-8.5

How do you to edit a formula that is not a formula field?  I can pick them in the foruma editor dropdown but that does not change the entry in the dropdown or code below.

I have a report I need to pull the logic from.  The display clearly shows many @formula output fields and I can view the logic behind them.  Some of the formulas reference other formulas that I can not find the definition of.

In formula editor for field: @field1

```
StringVar item:={table1.column1};
if item = 1 then
{@column2transformed}
else 
" "
```

Where is {@column2transformed} defined if not on the main report display? I can find it in the selection list with an "X.1" icon next to it.  I know which database field it is referencing in this simple example but can not afford to make assumptions about how the data is transformed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file I was working with was version 7, I was editing with version 8.5, using version 9 fixed this bug/issue.

Answer (score 0):

In Crystal Reports formulas `{@something}` indicates a reference to a Formula Field that has the name of `something`.

The `@` symbol is used to signify the field name used in the braces is a Formula Field.  There are other symbols used for other types of fields as well.

`?` is used for Parameter Fields

`#` is used for Running Total Fields

`@` is used for Formula Fields

`%` is used for SQL Expression Fields

I would also recommend you name your Formula Fields more descriptively.  Names such as `@something` and `@Field1` can become very confusing in the long-run.  Especially in discussions such as this where it isn't always apparent if the word used is a literal name or generalized expression.

Comment: Thank you.  I have clarified my question with your information.  My root problem is I cannot locate the logic behind the formula.  Where might it be defined in the editor that is not visible?  It is likely something simple I am missing due to a lack of familiarity with the editor.